# Unity Web Apps make separate window named Untitled in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webapps

NOTE: NOT CHROME WEB APPS... Unity Web Apps as introduced in 12.10...

When I make a Web App after installing the Chrome extensions for Unity Web Apps and Online Accounts, It opens a Web App in a new window... Seems fine.

However it makes two window icons on the Unity launcher even though only one window is open... Their is one with the app icon which is expected... Then their is a icon named Untitled which is all my Unity Web Apps open... The icon is sometimes the Chromium icon and sometimes the Square Question Mark Icon.

How do you fix this?

Comment: This issue is there even for me.